# Append 'punk beer api' page number to query parameter in a nuxt project

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search Beers e.g. Pale Ale" v-model="input" @keyup.enter="searchBeer" />
```

Although i added the search function in the input, it still isn't working

```
const input = ref("");
let pgNo = ref(1);

let url = `https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers?page=${pgNo.value}&per_page=12`;


const { data: beers, refresh, error} = await useFetch(
    () => url 
);
const searchBeer = async() => {
  const formattedSearch = input.value;
    url.concat(`&beer_name=${formattedSearch}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a [computed property](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html) for the `url`. Whenever the other refs change, the value of `url` will be automatically updated.

```html
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="searchBeer">
    <input
      v-model="beerName"
      type="text"
      placeholder="Search Beers e.g. Pale Ale"
    />
  </form>
</template>
```

```html
<script setup>
const beerName = ref('')
const pageNumber = ref(1)

const url = computed(() => {
  let str = `https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers?page=${pageNumber.value}&per_page=12`

  if (beerName.value) {
    str += `&beer_name=${beerName.value}`
  }

  return str
})

const searchBeer = async () => {
  const data = await $fetch(url.value)
  // ...
}
</script>
```

Comment: hey @salva-soosar this does work although
`const { data: beers, refresh, error } = await useFetch(`
`    () => url.value`
`);`

none of the beers show unless I type something in the search. I want the beers to show even though I typed nothing. If I type the search beer does show, that worked. although I need the beers to show.
thank you

Comment: nvm i used the ternary operators

Comment: Ah got it, I've updated my answer to handle optionally adding the `beer_name` query parameter.